# Merge rows based on value (pandas to excel - xlsxwriter) - addition

Tags: pandas

[Following up this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61217923/merge-rows-based-on-value-pandas-to-excel-xlsxwriter/61228294?noredirect=1#comment120527781_61228294)

I would like to ask if we could merge rows from multiple columns, i.e.

[image]

Following answers from @Dimitris Thomas, I would be able to obtain the following

[image]

And wondering how the code could be updated to get:

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IIUC:

Firstly:

```
df=pd.read_excel('filename.xlsx')
#read excel file in pandas
```

try via `set_index()` and `to_excel()`

```
df.set_index(df.columns[:-1].tolist()).to_excel('filename.xlsx',header=None)
#OR(Since you don't provide data as text so not sure which one should work)
df.set_index(df.columns.tolist()).to_excel('filename.xlsx',header=None)
```

Comment: Please can someone help me with this , im stuck with this from a long time , tried all possible ways but not working https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76331344/how-to-merge-empty-cells-in-a-pivot-table-using-python