# How to merge several cells in excel file exported with pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

[image]

My goal is to export this dataframe in excel file using `df.to_excel` but I want to merge all void cells and cells above these cells, like this:

[image]

How can I do that?

Edit:
My Dataframe looks like this:
[image]

And I created this Dataframe from a dict like :

```
{'Etat': 'Publié',
 'Type de produit': 'Plaque de plâtre',
 'Numéro': 'PP/22-43',
 'Titulaire': 'KNAUF ESPAGNE',
 'Usine': '20',
 "Date d'admission": '06/03/2014',
 'Date de reconduction': '04/02/2021',
 'Date de fin de validité': '04/05/2022',
 'Certificat PDF': 'https://webapp.cstb.fr/nf-platre/application/docs/certificats/PP_22_43.pdf'}
```

with `df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict, orient='index').T`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge rows based on value (pandas to excel - xlsxwriter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61217923/merge-rows-based-on-value-pandas-to-excel-xlsxwriter)

Comment: Thanks, I already saw this thread but I wondered if there is any built-in feature or at least more minimal way to merge all empty cells and the cell above by column

Answer (score 1):

Use `merge_cells=True` parameter of `to_excel()` like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
  
df = pd.DataFrame({'String1': {0: "string5", 1: "string5", 2: "string5",
                                 3: "string22", 4: "string22", 5: "string22"},
                          'String2': {0: 'string11', 1: 'string12', 2: 'string13', 
                                      3: 'string14',4: 'string15', 5: 'string16'},
                          'String3': {0: 'string31', 1: 'string32', 2: 'string33', 
                                      3: 'string34',4: 'string35', 5: 'string36'}})
  
mydf = df.set_index(["String1","String2"])

mydf.to_excel("MarksData.xlsx", merge_cells=True)
print('DataFrame is written to Excel File successfully.')
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help but it doesn't work for me. My Dataframe is created from a dict like this `product_data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(product_data, orient='index').T`
The dict format is : `"string1": "string2", "string3": "string4"`
I already try merge_cells=True but it doesn't work for my case

Comment: @Howins, welcome, I edit code block, Do you mean this?

Comment: Thank you, so I have to modify my dict to merge these cells? I can't merge all empty cells by column included the cells above in a Dataframe?

Comment: can you share your dataframe?

Comment: I edited my post to add more informations