# Python Pandas : separate values in row to new lines in row

Tags: python, pandas

table :

```
list_1=[['AA','MM asasas MM asasdad MM dfsdfd'],
        ['BB','MM dsfsdf MM fgdfgd MM dfgdfg'],
        ['CC','MM asfdsf MM kjhgkhjk MM jfghjfg']]
labels=['name','description']
df=pd.DataFrame(list_1,columns=labels)
df
```

Need to add rows within a row and get:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you first need to insert individual rows and then merge it based on name like this to get the desired result. The following post might be helpful for merging rows in Pandas

[Merge rows based on value (pandas to excel - xlsxwriter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61217923/merge-rows-based-on-value-pandas-to-excel-xlsxwriter)