# Groupby single column and merge using Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a dataframe df which i need to merge Department wise

**Input**
[image]

**My Output**
[image]

**Expected Output**
[image]

Comment: In a merge take part **two** DataFrames. You failed to show the second DataFrame (with which you merge your first DataFrame.
Another detail to correct: Put your source data (both DataFrames) as **text**, not a picture.
We have neither time nor desire to rewrite your source data from pictures. And show your code you tried so far. One more detail: What is the difference between your output and the desired output?

Comment: @gomathi, are you asking how to merge the *cells* in the excel output?

Comment: Yes @Jayvee, i want to merge the cells

Comment: @Gomathi You may need to do it with openpyxl or xslxwriter. This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61217923/merge-rows-based-on-value-pandas-to-excel-xlsxwriter