# Existing data in sheet to table

Tags: python, pandas, excel

i actually have a table in an excel sheet and i want to insert these data in a table.
I followed this answer and have exactly this kind of table
[Merge rows based on value (pandas to excel - xlsxwriter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61217923/merge-rows-based-on-value-pandas-to-excel-xlsxwriter)

Here is what i tried but it's not working

```
(max_row, max_col) = table_filld.shape
column_settings = [{"header": column} for column in table_filld.columns]

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
table_filld.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

column_settings = []
for header in df.columns:
    column_settings.append({'header': header})

worksheet.add_table(0, 0, max_row, max_col - 1, {"columns": column_settings})
merge_format = workbook.add_format({'align': 'center', 'valign': 'vcenter'})

lastRow = len(table_filld)-1

for row in startCells:
    try:
        endRow = startCells[startCells.index(row)+1]-1
        if row == endRow:
            worksheet.write(row+1, 0, table_filld.loc[row-1,'Questions'], merge_format)
        else:
            worksheet.merge_range(row+1, 0, endRow+1, 0, table_filld.loc[row,'Questions'], merge_format)
    except IndexError:
        if row == lastRow:
            worksheet.write(row+1, 0, table_filld.loc[row-2,'Questions'], merge_format)
        else:
            worksheet.merge_range(row+1, 0, lastRow+1, 0, table_filld.loc[row-1,'Questions'], merge_format)
            

writer.close()
```

how can i modify this code to insert directly in a table?
If i'm not clear feel free to ask me any questions.
Thanks in advance