# Can Pandas write excel files with merged cells?

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

I have some data that I want to export in an excel spread sheet. The data contains nested dictionaries with variable number of elements.

It looks like this

```
[{ "12345" :
    { "cup" : "123456789",
      "spoon" : "234567891",
    }
 },
 { "23456" :
    { "plate" : "345678912",
    }
 }
]
```

I want to export this data in an Excel spreadsheet that looks like this:

[image]

My data is more complex, but I guess if I understand how to get this done I can apply it myself.

So I was thinking about using the xlsxwriter python module, but I would have to loop thru the data to create the cells.
Then I remembered that Pandas has an easy way to import such data in a dataframe and has a nice excel export.

But I don't now if Pandas supports something like merged cells.

What would you suggest to use in such case?

Comment: If pandas cannot, openpyxl can.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge rows based on value (pandas to excel - xlsxwriter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61217923/merge-rows-based-on-value-pandas-to-excel-xlsxwriter)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61217923/merge-rows-based-on-value-pandas-to-excel-xlsxwriter

Comment: I was hoping that there might be a better way than to loop thru the data. But, yes it gives me hint how to start with.

Comment: If you load into Pandas. you'll have to do some formatting there anyway. Remember Xlsxwriter only able to create new work book/sheets. Other modules like Openpyxl and Xlwings and Pandas if you decide to use it can add to existing workbooks (Pandas has to use a different engine than the default Xlsxwriter) but all can achieve the same result.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with just Xlsxwriter.

This is an example, I have included some extra data in the list for show;

```
import xlsxwriter


data_list = [
    {"12345":
         {"cup": "123456789",
          "spoon": "234567891",
          }
     },
    {"23456":
         {"plate": "345678912",
          }
     },
    {"11111":
         {"knife": "12121212",
          "fork": "23232323",
          "spoon": "34343434"
          }
     },
    {"22222":
         {"cup": "56565656",
          "saucer": "67676767"
          }
     }
]

### New workbook and sheet
wb = xlsxwriter.Workbook('xlsxwriter_merge_example.xlsx')
ws = wb.add_worksheet()

### Cell formatting
header_format = wb.add_format({"bold": True, "num_format": "0", "align": "center", "valign": "vcenter", "border": 1})
cell_format_str = wb.add_format({"border": 1})
cell_format_num = wb.add_format({"num_format": "0", "border": 1})

ws.write(0, 0, 'Order', header_format)
ws.merge_range("B1:C1", "Item", header_format)


row_index = 1
for row_data in data_list:
    for col_index, (cell_key, cell_value) in enumerate(row_data.items()):
        if len(cell_value) >= 2:
            ws.merge_range(row_index,
                           col_index,
                           (row_index + len(cell_value)) - 1,
                           col_index,
                           int(cell_key),
                           header_format)
        else:
            ws.write(row_index, col_index, int(cell_key), header_format)
        for item_key, item_value in cell_value.items():
            ws.write(row_index, col_index + 1, item_key, cell_format_str)
            ws.write(row_index, col_index + 2, int(item_value), cell_format_num)
            row_index += 1

ws.autofit()
wb.close()
```

Output sheet with the extra data. 
Minimal amount of formatting has been applied. 
[image]