How to aggregate dataframe to keep certain column values in separate cells?
i am using python. i have a dataframe:
# Sample DataFrame
data = {
    'sto_num': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
    'sto_text': ['ab', 'ab', 'ab', 'k', 'k', 'b', 'b'],
    'tu_num': [2.2, 2.6, 3.5, 1.2, 1.3, 5.2, 5.1],
    'compliance': ['С', 'Н', 'Ч', 'С', 'Н', 'С', 'Ч'],
    'comment': ['с1', 'н1', 'ч1', 'с2', 'н2', 'с3', 'ч3']
}

sto_num        sto_text         tu_num          compliance               comment
1                 ab              2.2                С                     с1
-----------------------------------------------------------
1                 ab              2.6                Н                     н1
-----------------------------------------------------------
1                 ab              3.5                Ч                     ч1
-----------------------------------------------------------
2                  k                1.2                С                     с2
-----------------------------------------------------------
2                  k                1.3                Н                     н2
-----------------------------------------------------------
3                  b               5.2                С                     с3
-----------------------------------------------------------
3                  b               5.1                Ч                     ч3

i wrote this code to aggregate that dataframe:
df = df.groupby('sto_num').agg({
                        'sto_text': 'first',  # Assuming 'sto_text' is the same for each 'sto_num'
                        'tu_num': lambda x: '\n\n'.join(map(str, x)),
                        'compliance': lambda x: determine_compliance(x.tolist()),
                        'comment': lambda x: '\n\n'.join(map(str, x))
                    }).reset_index()

i want to aggregate it so tu_num, tu_text and comment of certain sto_num group not to be joined into one cell but to be in different cells of dataframe. so desired result looks like this:
sto_num    sto_text                     tu_num         compliance               comment
1                 ab                     2.2                                      с1
           ------------------------   ------------                        ------------------
                  ab                     2.6                                      н1
           ------------------------   ------------                        ------------------
                  ab                     3.5                Ч                     ч1
-----------------------------------------------------------
....

How to do that? Is it pssible for dataframe have different number of rows for differrent columns like in excel?
I havent found any good solution

did you try using multi-index and index hierarchy?

check this out - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61217923/merge-rows-based-on-value-pandas-to-excel-xlsxwriter

Short answer - No. Dataframes by design are a group of columns perfectly aligned across rows. A dataframe is to store data during processing stages, not a way to visualize it. I suggest you look into alternate viz solutions like excel using excelwriter.


How to do that? Is it pssible for dataframe have different number of rows for differrent columns like in excel?

No, this is not possible in Pandas.
You could however expand your dataframe, somewhat like this:
expanded_rows = []
for _, group in df.groupby('sto_num'):
    for i in range(len(group)):
        row = group.iloc[i].copy()
        if i > 0:
            row['sto_text'] = ''
        expanded_rows.append(row)

expanded_df = pd.DataFrame(expanded_rows)

This would yield a data frame where the sto_text column is only filled for the first row of each sto_num group:
   sto_num sto_text  tu_num compliance comment
0        1       ab     2.2          С      с1
1        1              2.6          Н      н1
2        1              3.5          Ч      ч1
3        2        k     1.2          С      с2
4        2              1.3          Н      н2
5        3        b     5.2          С      с3
6        3              5.1          Ч      ч3

